# Delete rows from datatable properly in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

Basically, I have a MySQL DB I'm binding the data from one column of a table into a ListBox.. I want to allow users to add/edit/remove items and to be able to save/reject changes

For deletion, I want the user to be able to delete the selected item in the ListBox.. here's what I've tried so far

(1) `dt.Rows(lst.SelectedIndex).Delete()`

But this doesn't actually delete the row from the DataTable until updating it using `DataAdapter.Update` method, so the next index in the ListBox will refer to the deleted row in the DataTable.

(2): `dt.Rows.RemoveAt(lst.SelectedIndex)`

This works fine, but when updating the DataTable (after the user clicks `save`), the deleted rows aren't even deleted.

(3) Tried calling `AcceptChanges`:

```
    dt.Rows(lst.SelectedIndex).Delete()
    dt.AcceptChanges()
```

And I get the same result as the second one above.

Here's how I finally update the DataTable:

```
    Dim cmdBldr As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Update(dt)
```

So, is there a way to allow users to add/delete any number of rows to the DataTable BEFORE updating it?

Comment: If you call both ('.Delete()' and  '.RemoveAt()') what happens?

Comment: I ended up using a `BindingSource` -thanks to jmcilhinney's answer-, but anyway what you're suggesting isn't a good idea because first of all it will delete two items from the listbox at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` (which you would add in the designer) and bind that to the `ListBox`.  You would then delete the selected record by calling `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`.  That will flag that row as `Deleted` and it will be excluded by the `BindingSource`.

DO NOT call `AcceptChanges` on anything.  Doing so will indicate to the data adapter that there are no changes to save.  Call `Update` on the data adapter to save the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.  That will call `AcceptChanges` internally after a successful save.  When `AcceptChanges` is called, any rows marked `Deleted` are removed from the `DataTable`, while any rows marked `Added` or `Modified` are marked `Unchanged`.

Comment: Thank you, the `BindingSource` solved the issue.. but I'm wondering is there a way to do this without using an extra `BindingSource` (by binding the `DataTable` directly to the `ListBox`)?

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to?  The `BindingSource` exists for a reason.

Comment: It was just because I'm binding 6-8 tables, but I already used a binding source for each table. Thank you again :)